# theme_hook process: calling a theme function not working(example from DGD7)

Tags: 7, theming

I'm just working through an example module in [DGD7](http://dgd7.org/). The module reports statistics about the themes. It displays this information in the help region on the appearance admin page.

I can't get it to display and I'm wondering if I understand the theming process correctly.

My understanding is this:

1. I call my function. (with a function)
2. My function returns data.
3. I tell drupal about my theme function with hook_theme
4. My theme function then turns my data into HTML.

Here's the module:

It uses a switch to call the function based on the path:

```
function xray_help($path, $arg) { 
 switch ($path) {
  case 'admin/appearance':
   return xray_appearance_summary();
 }
}
```

Then this function calls data from a stats function which returns a compact. (the stats function works - tested with dpm())

```
function xray_appearance_summary() {
  $data = array();
  $data['themes'] = xray_stats_enabled_themes();
  return $data;
}
```

They give a theme function (I'll put it last because it's quite long) but don't show how to call it with hook_theme. I tried using this hook_theme to call the theme function:

```
function xray_theme() {
  return array(
    'appearance_summary' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'themes' => NULL,
        'attr' => NULL,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

The theme function takes two variables $themes & $attr so I put both of those in. But I get the error.

Notice: Array to string conversion in menu_get_active_help() (line 1722 of C:\XAMPP\htdocs\drupal\includes\menu.inc).

Am I misunderstanding hook_theme?

```
function theme_xray_appearance_summary($variables) {
  $themes = $variables['data']['themes'];
  // Collapse attributes for paragraph tag to a string.
  $attr = drupal_attributes($variables['attributes']);

$output = '';
  $output .= "<p $attr>";
  $output .= t('This site');
  $output .= ' ';
  $output .= format_plural(
    $themes['num_themes'] - $themes['num_hidden'],
    'has only one theme available',
    'has @count themes available'
  );
  $output .= ' ';
  $output .= format_plural(
    $themes['num_hidden'],
    'plus one hidden theme.',
    'plus @count hidden themes.'
  );
  $output .= ' ';
  $output .= t('Of the non-hidden themes,');
  $output .= ' ';
  $output .= format_plural(
    $themes['num_enabled'],
    'one is enabled.  The enabled theme',
    '@count are enabled.  In the enabled themes,'
  );
  $output .= ' ';
  $summaries = array();
  foreach ($themes['summaries'] as $name => $info) {
    $summary = '';
    $summary .= $name . ' ';
    $summary .= format_plural(
      $info['regions'],
      'has one region',
      'has @count regions'
    );
    if ($info['overlay_regions'] || $info['regions_hidden']) {
      $summary .= ' ' . t('(including') . ' ';
      $summary .= format_plural(
        $info['overlay_regions'],
        'one overlay region',
        '@count overlay regions'
      );
      $summary .= ' ' . t('and') . ' ';
      $summary .= format_plural(
        $info['regions_hidden'],
        'one hidden region',
        '@count hidden regions'
      );
      $summary .= ')';
    }
    $summaries[] = $summary;
  }
  $output .= xray_oxford_comma_list($summaries);
  $output .= '.';
  $output .= '</p>';
  return $output;
}
```

EDIT ONE.

I've got rid of the error by changing the switch; thanks to Yuriy, but nothing still displays:

```
 case 'admin/appearance':
      $variables = array('data' => xray_appearance_summary());
      return theme('xray_appearance_summary', $variables);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I had two problems in the end. The first which I put in my edit above, was I needed to turn `$data` (an array) into a string. This was done by using the theme function to send the `$data` to the theme which then themes it and sends it back as a string.

```
case 'admin/appearance':
     $variables = array('data' => xray_appearance_summary());
     return theme('xray_appearance_summary', $variables);
```

The second was my hook_theme. It's receiving `$data` from `xray_summary_appearance`. Not `$themes` from the theme function.

```
function xray_theme() {
  return array(
    'xray_appearance_summary' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'data' => array(),
        'attributes' => array('class' => 'xray-help'),
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `theme_xray_appearance_summary` should be `theme_appearance_summary`, and should take `$variables` by reference: `&$variables`.

Second of all, `hook_help()` expects you to return a string, but your implementation returns the data from `xray_appearance_summary()`, which returns an array, thus the error you're getting.

Comment: I based some of my syntax off the theming example module. It uses theme_theming_example_content_array($variables) as a theme function. Why would that syntax not work for mine?

Comment: Separated into two comments for clarity. On the second point I thought that the theme function takes $data from x_ray_appearance_summary and turns it into a the string (held in $output) which is then passed back. Otherwise how is the theming function involved?